# storing backbone model and collections in phonegap singlep page apps before sync

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, local-storage, synchronization

I am developing single page phonegap applications and I am using backbone, require.js, underscore.
Say that I need to enter patient, and doctor information. This means I have backbone model for patient and doctor. Now, I may enter 3 patient and 3 doctor information. That mean i have to form collection of pateint and doctor. Now, when the device is offline, I want to store them locally. And when the device is online, i want to sync them to server.

I am just wondering what will be the good idea here to use. Should i use phonegap sqlite, or backbone adopter for local storage or html5 local storage for efficient and reliable means?
And can anyone suggest me to some sample on git hub to do this or any examples on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on right track. There are several step to accomplish it, each of it could represent it's own problem.

1. Detect that application goes offline.
2. Once it offine, switch `Backbone.Sync` from ajax-based, to localstore (you mentioned sqllite, if there are API in JavaScript for that and Backbone plugin it's nice too).
3. You track all "sync" that happens during offline mode.
4. Once application goes online again, all not-sync changes uploads to server.

Please check [Backbone-offine](https://github.com/ask11/backbone-offline) repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

- [indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter](https://github.com/superfeedr/indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter)
- [IndexedDBShim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim)

The first is an addapter for backbone to use IndexedDB (HTML5 native), and the second is for platforms without IndexedDB but with WebSQL (Androids < 19 for ex).

This override the `Backbone.sync` function, but you can define the sync method of a collection/model with `Backbone.ajaxSync` if you want to sync by ajax (see [here](https://github.com/superfeedr/indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter#optional-persistence)).

I'm using this and works well, but if you need to manage a lot of records I recommend you to use an SQLite (native) connector. In your case I thinks IndexedDB is ok.